# When should I use javascript or PHP facebook SDKs for login activities

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm building a PHP web application, something like "Auction", I want to let the user to sign in using their facebook accounts.

I started using javascript SDK, I've built the first page in which I asked the user to login using facebook, after the authentication is made, the page refreshes and according to some cookies I stored after the authentication, the page layout and elements change.

I want to save the login status in such a way the server knows if the user is authenticated or not, I know I can same the appropriate cookies to give the server these information, so do I need the PHP SDK in the future? Is it better if the retrieving of user info done in PHP at server side? what advantages I get from using the PHP SDK rather than using the javascript?

I'm sill in the very beginning of the development process, and I'm not sure if I'm going the right way to use the javascript SDK alone! any help concerning this dilemma will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: So how do you get information on server from client-side?

Comment: Why do I need to get information from server in the client-side? I might need do the opposite using cookies, but I could do the same using cookies too, right?

Comment: "I could do the same using cookies too, right" --- right, that's what php sdk is doing. So why reimplement it?

Comment: so typically I don't need to use PHP SDK at all! Thanks :)

Comment: if you need it - you need it, if you don't need it - you don't need it.

Comment: of course, my question was: when may I need it? what is it mostly for? because I don't want to build a shaky app and start over again when I find new requirements.

Comment: you need it when you need to work with FB API from php